# How to copy one ODS sheet into other file?

Tags: perl, openoffice.org, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, odf

Thought that copying one sheet from one ODF file into other is piece of cake. Unfortunately even simplest code below ends with empty new file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.014; use utf8::all;
use ODF::lpOD;

my $doc = odf_get_document( "olddoc.ods" )
  or die "Failed to load the document\n";

my $table = $doc->get_body->get_table_by_position(0);

my $newdoc = odf_new_document('spreadsheet');
my $context = $newdoc->get_body;
my $newtable = $context->insert_element( $table );

$newdoc->save(target => "newdoc.ods");
```

Only output I see is `Element already belonging to a tree`.

Do you see why it fails to create new doc with first sheet of old document?

Comment: This happens with DOM too (and that's likely the underlying implementation). http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#importNode

Comment: @Kenney don't follow you, do you care more specific explanation?

Comment: It's just a guess - I couldn't find the dependencies of `ODF::lpOD` to be sure, but, Elements ($el) are owned by a Document ($doc). If you want to insert an $el into a $doc, then $doc must have either created the element, or it must have [adopted](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#adoptNode) it.

Comment: @Kenney So I must clone the table before I could insert into new doc?

Comment: I think `$newtable->adoptNode( $table );` before the `insert_element` should do it. If you clone, you still have to transfer ownership - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605158/perl-xmldom-copy-node-tree-between-files).

Comment: @Kenney: actually it was still cloning like `my $newtable = $table->clone;` before insert. You could form it as an answer. Thank you!